# How to use sysenter under Linux?

Tags: assembly, x86

I would like to know what are the different ways to perform a system
call in x86 assembler under Linux. But, with no cheating, only
assembler must be used (i.e. compilation with `gcc` must be done with
`-nostdlib`).

I know four ways to perform a system calls, namely:

- `int $0x80`
- `sysenter` (i586)
- `call *%gs:0x10` (vdso trampoline)
- `syscall` (amd64)

I am pretty good at using `int $0x80`, for example, here is a sample
code of a classic 'Hello World!' in assembler using `int $0x80` (compile it with `gcc -nostdlib -o hello-int80 hello-int80.s`):

```
.data
msg:
  .ascii "Hello World!\n"
  len = . - msg

.text
.globl _start

_start:
# Write the string to stdout
  movl  $len, %edx
  movl  $msg, %ecx
  movl  $1, %ebx
  movl  $4, %eax
  int   $0x80

# and exit
  movl  $0, %ebx
  movl  $1, %eax
  int   $0x80
```

But the `sysenter` is often ending with a segmentation fault error. Why ? And, how to use it right ?

Here is an example with `call *%gs:0x10` (compiled with `gcc -o hello-gs10 hello-gs10.s`). Note that I need to go through the `libc` initialization before calling it properly (that is why I am using `main` and not anymore `_start` and, that is also why I removed the option `-nostdlib` from the compile line):

```
.data
msg:
  .ascii "Hello World!\n"
  len = . - msg

.text
.globl main

main:
# Write the string to stdout
  movl  $len, %edx
  movl  $msg, %ecx
  movl  $1, %ebx
  movl  $4, %eax
  call  *%gs:0x10

# and exit
  movl  $0, %ebx
  movl  $1, %eax
  call  *%gs:0x10
```

Also, the `syscall` is working pretty well also if you know the [syscall codes for this architecture](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.32/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h) (thanks to lfxgroove) (compiled with: `gcc -m64 -nostdlib -o hello-syscall hello-syscall.s`):

```
.data
msg:
  .ascii "Hello World!\n"
  len = . - msg

.text
.globl _start

_start:
# Write the string to stdout
  movq  $len, %rdx
  movq  $msg, %rsi
  movq  $1, %rdi
  movq  $1, %rax
  syscall
# and exit
  movq  $0, %rdi
  movq  $60, %rax
  syscall
```

So, the only problem I have to trigger a system call is this `sysenter` way. Here is an example with `sysenter` ending with a segmentation fault (compiled with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -o hello-sysenter hello-sysenter.s`):

```
.data
msg:
  .ascii "Hello World!\n"
  len = . - msg

.text
.globl _start

_start:
# Write the string to stdout
  movl  $len, %edx
  movl  $msg, %ecx
  movl  $1, %ebx
  movl  $4, %eax

  push    final
  sub $12, %esp
  mov %esp, %ebp

  sysenter
# and exit
final:  
  movl  $0, %ebx
  movl  $1, %eax

  sub $12, %esp
  mov %esp, %ebp

  sysenter
```

Comment: A first guess for the syscall try is that you've got the wrong syscall numbers as it seems that for 64-bits mode (which it seems syscall is for) the numbers are all scrambled, ie: exit is 60 instead of what you're using right now, see http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.32/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h for the numbers

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I was really puzzled but it seems that in my example it was the second `syscall` that was calling the `write` (and not the first one, as I was expecting).

Comment: Rather than making another QA. @perror would you mind explaining `len = . - msg` - _edit_ : I know of the purpose by obvious reasons but the semantics of it. - Thanks

Comment: The '`.`' in the gas syntax refer to the current address. So, `len = . - msg` is a way to store in `len` the size of the string `msg` (it computes the difference between the current address and the position of the `msg` label).

Comment: Question, is syscall and sysenter architecture specific? As far as i can tell i have a intel which would mean i can use sysenter but the compiled code has syscall in it. Am i missing something?

Comment: @lfxgroove plz share the answer for above question you asked about syscall(in case you found it)

Comment: @shami, sorry i didn't :(

Comment: To ensure correct syscall numbers, might I suggest #include <sys/syscalls.h> and then $SYS_write, $SYS_exit etc. in your code instead of $4, $1

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped me figure out [this systemd assertion failure](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11974) on a bugged ChromiumOS kernel by layong out the different ways how syscalls can be made and the code example in the answer.

Comment: Congrats nh2! That was a very nice bug hunt! I really enjoyed reading this bug report summary on GitHub (and your explanations are really good!). SIncerely, I would never have expected that my explanations of the `sysenter` instruction could be of any use for anybody and you proved me wrong! ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### System calls through `sysenter`

`sysenter` is a i586 instruction, specifically tight to 32-bits
applications. It has been subsumed by `syscall` on 64-bits plateforms.

One particularity of `sysenter` is that it does require, in addition
to the usual register setting, a few manipulations on the stack before
calling it. This is because before leaving `sysenter`, the process
will go through the last part of the `__kernel_vsyscall` assembler
snippet (starting from `0xf7ffd430`):

```
Dump of assembler code for function __kernel_vsyscall:
   0xf7ffd420 <+0>:        push   %ecx
   0xf7ffd421 <+1>:        push   %edx
   0xf7ffd422 <+2>:        push   %ebp
   0xf7ffd423 <+3>:        mov    %esp,%ebp
   0xf7ffd425 <+5>:        sysenter 
   0xf7ffd427 <+7>:        nop
   0xf7ffd428 <+8>:        nop
   0xf7ffd429 <+9>:        nop
   0xf7ffd42a <+10>:       nop
   0xf7ffd42b <+11>:       nop
   0xf7ffd42c <+12>:       nop
   0xf7ffd42d <+13>:       nop
   0xf7ffd42e <+14>:       int    $0x80
=> 0xf7ffd430 <+16>:       pop    %ebp
   0xf7ffd431 <+17>:       pop    %edx
   0xf7ffd432 <+18>:       pop    %ecx
   0xf7ffd433 <+19>:       ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

So, the `sysenter` instruction expect to have the stack forged in that
way:

```
0x______0c  saved_eip   (ret)
0x______08  saved_%ecx  (pop %ecx)
0x______04  saved_%edx  (pop %edx)
0x______00  saved_%ebp  (pop %ebp)
```

That's why, each time we need to call `sysenter`, we first have to
push the values of the saved `%eip`, and the same with`%ecx`, `%edx`
and `%ebp`. Which leads to:

```
.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello World!\n"
    len = . - msg

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    pushl  %ebp
    movl   %esp, %ebp
# Write the string to stdout
    movl   $len, %edx
    movl   $msg, %ecx
    movl   $1, %ebx
    movl   $4, %eax
# Setting the stack for the systenter
    pushl  $sysenter_ret
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebp
    movl   %esp,%ebp
    sysenter
# and exit
sysenter_ret:    
    movl   $0, %ebx
    movl   $1, %eax
# Setting the stack for the systenter
    pushl  $sysenter_ret # Who cares, this is an exit !
    pushl  %ecx
    pushl  %edx
    pushl  %ebp
    movl   %esp,%ebp
    sysenter
```

Comment: I really do not know how the Linux kernel can re-route the result of the instruction `sysenter` to `__kernel_vsyscall+16`. If somebody can clarify this for me, I would be pleased.

Comment: it's via the MSR called registers , http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_313.html , in SYSEXIT they used those registers too. Don't know how they were setten up or what is the source files they were declared in.

Comment: @perror in fact you don't have to push anything on the stack to exit, just make sure `ebp` has an accessible address, so that the kernel reads ahead the potential 6th syscall argument without #GP (the value doesn't have to mean anything, so no need to push `ebp` too). I. e. the exit call would reduce to `mov eax,1; xor ebx,ebx; mov ebp, esp; sysenter`.

Comment: @Ruslan I'm afraid code you suggested just doesn't work - program terminates with segfault.

Comment: @AleksanderAlekseev what Linux version are you using? And what do you have in `esp`?

Comment: @Ruslan, sorry, I just realized that you suggested to modify only exit() call, not both write() and exit() calls. In this case everything works fine.

Comment: It would be great to link to the part of the kernel code where you see the stack expectations.

Comment: It is located in `arch/x86/entry/vdso/vdso32-setup.c`. But, it does not really pop up with a better understanding of how it works when you read it. :)

Comment: If you don't mind garbage being put in ecx, edx and ebp (such as when you're going to be overwriting those value anyway) you can instead use `lea ebp, [esp-12]`

Comment: Are you sure it's sysenter requiring stack set up? The way I understand it, those should be values for sysexit, so it knows where to return and restore to previous stack. So I would say it's kernel that works with the values from the stack, but maybe that's what you meant. In the last code snippet, what does the second sysenter do?