# How does sysenter instruction in windows 7 work?

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, kernel-mode

How does the sysenter instruction work?
What instruction is called after sysenter?
Is the next instruction saved in a register?

```
mov     edx,esp
sysenter
```

Comment: it goes into ring 0 typically with edx pointing to the parameters and eax being the 'id' of what to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does sysenter work under Linux?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/how-does-sysenter-work-under-linux)

Comment: I am suspecting that `sysenter` works the same for Linux and Windows... But, I didn't try with Windows, so you need to try out.

Comment: @perror: the linked question explains how to use `sysenter` to call Linux syscalls. It does not explain how `systenter` works on the CPU level.

Comment: @Igor : Right, I probably misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky  Dear Friends i have problem to understand this instruction  address calling after doing this and  Which address set on EIP.Input Parameters of instructions which?I have an exception  in my program and try debugging in windbg but i can't debug after this instruction.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a perfect explanation how `sysenter` works: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=257

In essence:
All native API calls from User Mode have a body that simply loads an index into EAX, executes `SystemCallStub`, and returns

SystemCallStub saves a pointer to the top of the User Mode stack into EDX and executes a SYSENTER instruction

SYSENTER disables interrupts, switches the thread into Kernel Mode and executes the instruction located in the SYSENTER_EIP_MSR (which on XP SP1 is KiFastCallEntry)

`KiFastCallEntry` builds a trap frame so it knows where to go when returning back to User Mode, enables interrupts, and jumps into `KiSystemService`

`KiSystemService`, amongst doing other things, copies the parameters from the User stack (pointed to by EDX) and takes the value previously stored in EAX and executes the function located at KiServiceTable[EAX]

The native API now executes in Kernel Mode with the previous mode of the thread set to User Mode

Comment: exactly can you say where save address eiP after call sysenter in returning to user mode?in stack or register?

Comment: a trap frame is used and setup for EIP after returning to user-mode. read about how trap frames work exactly

Comment: Did you mean Nowhere saving?
can you show me a reference about trap frames work?
tanx

Comment: the trap frame is set in kernel-mode so you cant modify it from user-mode. If you want to learn more, search for "interrupts, traps, exceptions"

Answer (score 3):

The `SYSENTER` instruction affects many registers, but most importantly it sets `EIP` to the value of the `SYSENTER_EIP_MSR` register (in IA-32 terminology). At boot-time, Windows sets `SYSENTER_EIP_MSR` to the address of `ntoskrnl!KiFastCallEntry()`.

So at a high-level, `SYSENTER` "jumps" to `ntoskrnl!KiFastCallEntry()`.

For more details, see http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/system/article.php/c8223/%22System-Call-Optimization-with-the-SYSENTER-Instruction.htm and http://trapframe.org/just-enough-kernel-to-get-by-2/.